# Trying to install npm package resulting in EEXIST error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, zurb-foundation, lightgallery

In a [Foundation for sites](https://foundation.zurb.com/) project im trying to add [Lightgallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightgallery) as an npm package.

But it will not install, resulting in this error about Gulp:

```
➜  foundation-6.4.3 npm i lightgallery
npm ERR! path [thePathTo]/foundation-6.4.3/node_modules/.bin/gulp
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete [thePathTo]/foundation-6.4.3/node_modules/.bin/gulp: is outside [thePathTo]/foundation-6.4.3/node_modules/gulp and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: [thePathTo]/foundation-6.4.3/node_modules/.bin/gulp
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I have tried to delete the file, move it away etc. but it result an almost identically error, stating that 
`[thePathTo]/foundation-6.4.3/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/.bin/window-size`
should be moved.

If I delete the `node_modules` folder and runs `npm install` I get a new `node_modules` folder, but with the node packages I have globally (354 folders) instead of the packages listed in `package.json` (36 folders)

**npm version: 6.3.0**

**node version: v8.5.0**

**Gulp** CLI version 1.3.0 – Local version 4.0.0-alpha.3

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: the reason for having more folders in node_modules than the 36 specified in the package.json is that these packages have dependencies that they require. This results in additional packages being installed to support the packages you requested. Confirm you have the appropriate versions specified and that it works with your versions of NPM, Node, and Gulp. You can view this on the NPM page for the package.

Comment: Please provide some info about the npm version. This seems to be only related to npm.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have provided the version info in my question.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this problem. @DanielRuf can you help?

Comment: Did the install of the needed package work so far? If yes, everything should be fine.